# biblatex - Manually replace dash with en dash in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use biblatex, biber with the style [biblatex-philosophy](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-philosophy?lang=en). Unfortunately, the page ranges in the bibliography are produced with a regular dash and not an en dash.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
As described by \textcite{lewis1979a}, blabla.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the used bib-resource:

```
@article{lewis1979a,
    Author = {David Lewis},
    Journal = {Philosophical Review},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {513--543},
    Title = {Attitudes \emph{{D}e {D}icto} and \emph{{D}e {S}e}},
    Volume = {88},
    Year = {1979}}
```

The output:
[image]

Question: Is there a way to globally replace the dash with an en dash in the bibliography?

Comment: The command in question is `\bibrangedash`. You can redefine it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `philosophy-classic` style changes `\bibrangedash` to a hyphen. You can revert it by issuing an appropriate `\DefineBibliographyExtras` command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lewis1979a,
    Author = {David Lewis},
    Journal = {Philosophical Review},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {513--543},
    Title = {Attitudes \emph{De Dicto} and \emph{De Se}},
    Volume = {88},
    Year = {1979},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\protected\def\bibrangedash{\textendash}}

\begin{document}
As described by \textcite{lewis1979a}, blabla.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that the `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Comment: That should be reported as a bug in the style I think :-)

Comment: @JosephWright I believe it's a conscious decision based on some Italian tradition. Perhaps Ivan could add an option for switching back to the en-dash.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you very much. This solved the issue. I've contacted Ivan with the issue.

Comment: In my case helped `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\protected\def\bibrangedash{-}}`

Answer (score 0):

A more complete way on page 20 of [the package documentation](https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-philosophy/biblatex-philosophy.pdf) is

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
\protected\def\bibrangedash{%
\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty}%
\protected\def\bibdaterangesep{\bibrangedash}}%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{italian}{%
\protected\def\bibrangedash{%
\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty}%
\protected\def\bibdaterangesep{\bibrangedash}}%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{%
\protected\def\bibrangedash{%
\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty}%
\protected\def\bibdaterangesep{\bibrangedash}}%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
\protected\def\bibrangedash{%
\textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty}%
\protected\def\bibdaterangesep{\bibrangedash}}%
```